# How do I update the Date part only of a DateTime value in Apex code?

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a Controller in which I need to update the StartDateTime of an Event, but only the Date part of the field - the time needs to stay the same. How do I do this? Do I need to extract the Time part from the old date first and then do a datetime.parse with the new date and the old time?

Or is there some nifty function that will only update the Date part?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can leverage the built in function for adding only the days

**.addDays method**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_addDays

Comment: That would work, but there doesn't seem to be a DateDiff function in apex in order to determine the number of days to add - I need to calculate the difference between the old date and the new date.

Answer (score 2):

Combined with @ZenSeeker's help and what I found on another blog this is what works:

```
 integer intDays =  e.StartDateTime.Date().daysBetween(new.EventDate__c);
 e.StartDateTime = e.StartDateTime.addDays(intDays);
```